# In R, is it possible to call a function in a text paragraph and remove the breaks?

Tags: r, function, unicode, line-breaks

I am trying to write a function for non R users for report writing in R markdown.
The function calls unicode for macron characters.

CODE:

```
library(stringr)
library(Unicode)
library(htmltools)
library(cat)

mac <- function(x){
         if (x == "a") {
  result <- "\u101"
  } else if (x == "A") {
  result <- "\u100"
  } else if (x == "e") {
  result <- "\u113"
  } else if (x == "E") {
  result <- "\u112"
  } else if (x == "i") {
  result <- "\u12b"
  } else if (x == "I") {
  result <- "\u12a"
  } else if (x == "o") {
  result <- "\u14d"
  } else if (x == "O") {
  result <- "\u14c"
  } else if (x == "u") {
  result <- "\u16b"
  } else if (x == "U") {
  result <- "\u16a"
  } else (print("Entry not recognised")) 
  
  result = paste0(result, sep = "")

  return(result)
  # return(p(paste0(result, sep = "")))
  
}
```

I have tried:

```
  # gsub("[\r\n]", "", result)
  # str_replace_all(x, "[\r\n]" , "")
```

Without any success - I realise this is because there are no spaces around the output of the function to remove.

As an example, I want this:

```
p('Something',mac("a"),'nd something with a macron')
```

To read:

Something ānd something with a macron.

Comment: you should use `switch`, it will be much easier to read and less verbose: `result <- switch(x, a  = '\u101', A = '\u100', ..., U = '\u16a', stop('Entry not recognised'))`

Comment: @rawr Wow - that's a game changer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting multiple lines because you're passing a list to `p()`.

If you wrap the text in `paste0` the output should all be on one line.

Input:

`p(paste0('Something ',mac("a"),'nd something with a macron'))`

Output:

`<p>Something ānd something with a macron</p>`

Which displays as:

Something ānd something with a macron

This can be wrapped in a single function:

`p <- function(...) htmltools::p(paste0(...))`

If you anticipate users trying to pass lists to p() then you could add something to handle those exceptions.

Full code with example use:

```
library(stringr)
library(Unicode)
library(htmltools)
library(cat)

mac <- function(x){
    if (x == "a") {
        result <- "\u101"
    } else if (x == "A") {
        result <- "\u100"
    } else if (x == "e") {
        result <- "\u113"
    } else if (x == "E") {
        result <- "\u112"
    } else if (x == "i") {
        result <- "\u12b"
    } else if (x == "I") {
        result <- "\u12a"
    } else if (x == "o") {
        result <- "\u14d"
    } else if (x == "O") {
        result <- "\u14c"
    } else if (x == "u") {
        result <- "\u16b"
    } else if (x == "U") {
        result <- "\u16a"
    } else (print("Entry not recognised")) 
    
    result = paste0(result, sep = "")
    
    return(result)
    # return(p(paste0(result, sep = "")))
    
}

# wrap input in paste0() to create a string then pass to p()
p <- function(...) htmltools::p(paste0(...))

# example use
p('Something ',mac("a"),'nd something with a macron')
```

Comment: Right, thank you! Is it possible call that within the function? As opposed to giving the writers an extra step? I am trying to make this easier for them - perhaps this function isn't the solution?

Comment: Yes that would work, I'll add the wrapper to my solution.

Comment: I am not picking up what you're putting down - I am a novice in R - does that go around my function or inside it? I tried both and tried to return p_ but I can't get it to go. Your continued help has been invaluable.

Comment: I've added an example with the full code, all it is doing is creating another function p_() and saying that for ... (which is any input) pass that input to paste0 to create a single string from the list and then pass that string to p() to create a html paragraph.

Comment: Awesome - not quite inside the other function. But probably manageable for report writing - Appreciate the help. I have been stuck here for a while and didn't consider writing a second function.

Comment: If you're not worried about users having no access to the original function you could totally rename it like this ```p <- function(...) htmltools::p(paste0(...))```

Comment: good idea. I have since figured out that in R markdown I can call the function inline and do not need the second p_() function. E.g. Test the T`r macron("e") `n`r macron("a")` koe.